# Using Trig to integrate$\frac{ (x^3)}{(\sqrt{1 + x^2})}$

Tags: calculus, integration

For the integration of $\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$, can we use $tan(\theta)$ to substitute $x$, and then use $u= sec(\theta)$ later this proof? I got a solution which is $\frac{((sec^3 (tan^{-1} x))}{3}$$ - (sec (tan^{-1} (x)) + C)$. Is this method correct?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

A faster way to do the integration might be to set $u = x^2+1$. Then we have

\begin{align}
\int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} dx &= \int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} xdx \\
&= \int \frac{u-1}{\sqrt{u}} \frac{1}{2}du \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int \sqrt{u} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} du \\
\end{align}

I'll assume you can take it from here.

Comment: yes, you answer is absolutely correct! I just wonder what's wrong with my answer. If we use different methods of integration, can we get different answers?

Comment: Two correct answers may differ by a sometimes non-obvious constant. To check whether your answer is right, differentiate.  You would probably be expected to simplify your complicated inverse trig expressions. For example, what is the sec of $\tan^{-1}x$? A triangle may help.

Comment: @overpro one way to simplify your answer is to note that $\arctan x$ is the angle of a right triangle with leg length $x$ across from the angle, $1$ as the length of the other leg, and $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ as the hypotenuse. With this you can simplify your $\sec (\arctan x))$ expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do the substitution $x=\tan\theta$, for $\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, so
$$
\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}=\frac{1}{\cos\theta}
$$
and
$$
dx=\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta
$$
Then the integral is
$$
\int\tan^3\theta\cos\theta\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta=
\int\frac{\sin^3\theta}{\cos^4\theta}\,d\theta
$$
Now use $\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta$ and set $u=\cos\theta$, so the integral becomes
$$
\int\frac{u^2-1}{u^4}\,du
$$
that is elementary.