# Integration-by-part

Tags: integration

Here is the given question

$$\int{\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx}$$

I solved using integration by part as follow:
$$
\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}x^2\,dx = x^2\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,dx - \int\biggl(\frac{dx^2}{dx}\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx\biggr)dx\tag{i}\label{i}
$$

Solving for $\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and taking $1+x^2 = t \rightarrow 2xdx = dt \rightarrow xdx = \frac{dt}{2}$.

\begin{align}
&\int \frac{xdx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \int\frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t}}\\
&\int\frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t}} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{t^{\frac{-1}{2}+1}}{\frac{-1}{2}+1} \rightarrow \sqrt{t} = \sqrt{1+x^2}
\end{align}

Pluggin in equation \eqref{i}

$$\int{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}x^2dx} = x^2\sqrt{1+x^2} - 2\int{x\sqrt{1+x^2}dx}\tag{ii}\label{ii}$$

Now solving for $\int{x\sqrt{1+x^2}dx}$.

Assuming $1+x^2 = t \rightarrow xdx = \frac{dt}{2}$

$$\frac{1}{2}  \int\sqrt{t}dt \rightarrow \frac{\sqrt[3]{t}}{3} \text{  or   }
\int{x\sqrt{1+x^2}dx} =  \frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}}{3}$$

Pluggin in equation

$$\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}x^2dx = x^2\sqrt{1+x^2} - 2 \frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x^2}}{3} + C$$

But given answer is:

$$\frac{1}{3}(1+x^2)^{3/2}-(1+x^2)^{1/2}+C$$

What is wrong with my solution?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of [Using Trig to integrate$\frac{ (x^3)}{(\sqrt{1 + x^2})}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877254/using-trig-to-integrate-frac-x3-sqrt1-x2). By the way, why don't you use substitution?

Comment: @TobyMak by substitution you mean using Trig function? I solved it using Trig function but to practice more I used above procedure. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, I thought you could use any method to solve your question.

Comment: @Shubhanshu substitute $x=\tan\theta$

Comment: @ArjunBanerjee That goes against the point of the OP's comment. The OP wants to practice using integration by parts.

Comment: @TobyMak After substitution, the integration by parts will be much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

$$\int{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}*x^2dx} = x^2\sqrt{1+x^2} - 2\cdot \frac{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}{3} + C$$

Use

$$x^2\sqrt{1+x^2}=(x^2+1-1)\sqrt{1+x^2}=(1+x^2)^{3/2}-(1+x^2)^{1/2}$$ to match with the given answer

Comment: Almost solved but didn't perform simplification. So, you did thank you, Sir.

Comment: @Shubhanshu, Not required though. But hope you have noticed the minor mistake at the last of your calculation

Comment: Yeah, the simplification to match exactly what is given as the answer. By the way, the answer is correct.

Comment: @Shubhanshu, One suggestion: for $$\int\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{f(x^2)}dx$$ start replacing $x^2$ with $y$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}\displaystyle\int\dfrac{x^3}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,\mathrm dx&=\dfrac12\displaystyle\int\dfrac{x^2\mathrm d(x^2)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\\&=\dfrac12\displaystyle\int\dfrac{(1+x^2)-1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm d(x^2)\\&=\dfrac12\displaystyle\int\sqrt{1+x^2}\mathrm d(x^2)-\dfrac12\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\mathrm d(x^2)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\\&=\dfrac12\displaystyle\int\sqrt{1+x^2}\mathrm d(1+x^2)-\dfrac12\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\mathrm d(1+x^2)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\\&=\dfrac13(1+x^2)^{\frac32}-\sqrt{1+x^2}+C\end{align}